# Simple grammar not working

Tags: antlr

I have a simple grammar to parse files containing identifiers and keywords between brackets (hopefully):

```
grammar Keyword;

// PARSER RULES
//
entry_point :   ('['ID']')*;

// LEXER RULES
//
KEYWORD     :   '[Keyword]';

ID      :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
WS      :   ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\r\n') 
            {
                $channel = HIDDEN;
            };
```

It works for input:

```
[Hi]
[Hi]
```

It returns a NoViableAltException error for input:

```
[Hi]
[Ki]
```

If I comment KEYWORD, then it works fine. Also, if I change my grammar to:

```
grammar Keyword;

// PARSER RULES
//
entry_point :   ID*;

// LEXER RULES
//
KEYWORD     :   '[Keyword]';

ID      :   '[' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ']';
WS      :   ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\r\n') 
            {
                $channel = HIDDEN;
            };
```

Then it works. Could you please help me figuring out why?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1<sup>st</sup> grammar fails because whenever the lexer *sees* `"[K"`, the lexer will enter the `KEYWORD` rule. If it then encounters something other then `"eyword]"`, `"i"` in your case, it tries to go back to some other rule that *can* match `"[K"`. But there is no other lexer rule that starts with `"[K"` and will therefor throw an exception. Note that the lexer doesn't remove `"K"` and then tries to match again (the lexer is a *dumb* machine)!

Your 2<sup>nd</sup> grammar works, because the lexer now *can* find something to fall back on when `"[Ki"` does not get matched by the `KEYWORD` since `ID` now includes the `"["`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any theoritical or architectural reason why the lexer is not "coming back" until it finds a match?

Comment: @Korchkidu, not that I know of. I believe the next version of ANTLR (v4), the lexer will get "smarter" and is able to backtrack from #1 (not 100% sure though...)